# C++: Taking input outside of active window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input, keymapping

I want to have a function mapped to a key while my program is running, like a hotkey, even when it is running in the background. Using the Windows API, how can I make my program detect input outside of the active window?

Comment: You can do this with a keyboard hook: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I guess the user will hate this

Comment: Should the active program also get the "1" keystroke ? I.e. steal or copy?

Comment: [Look at this](https://github.com/udit043/shortcut-key-s/blob/master/lazy-finger.cpp), probably this is the same what you want.